Is $1$ a perfect number?
A perfect number can be defined as a number where all unique pairs of numbers that multiply to equal said number add up to the number itself times two, $6$ is perfect because $1+6+2+3=12$, $28$ is perfect because $1+28+2+14+4+7=56$. This would allow for 1 to be perfect because 1*1 is a unique pair of numbers, and $1+1=2$. Why should 6 be the first perfect number? 1 fits the bill quite nicely.

From Wikipedia: "A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its positive proper divisors, that is, divisors excluding the number itself."

A priori, the two definitions may not be equivalent for squares, because if $n$ is a square then the sum you're describing is equal to $\sigma_1(n)+\sqrt n$. Incidentally this is also the reason why $\text{yoursum}(1)=2$.

I can't tell whether your definition of perfect square matches the standard one on every square greater than one. Showing it does would be an interesting little proof.

The divisor sum is not allowed to have duplicate terms. E.g. the divisor sum for $9$ is $1+3+9$, not $1+9+3+3$, nor $1+9+3+3+9+1$ where we count $(1,9)$ and $(9,1)$ separately. Similarly the divisor sum for $1$ should be $1$, not $1+1$.

We say a number is perfect when it equals the sum of its divisors other than itself. As you mentioned, $6$ is a perfect number because its factors are $1,2,3,6$ and after eliminating $6$ we get $1+2+3=6$.
The factor of $1$ is just $1$ which must be eliminated because it is itself. So the sum of factors of $1$ other than itself is $0$ and $0\not=1$. Therefore $1$ is not a perfect number. I hope this helps.

Grey, you hope your answer helps but I hope you will not answer low-quality questions anymore.
